# jQuery scrollTop in <select> is not working in Chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, select, scroll, scrolltop

I have this jQuery JS fiddle which is working fine in FF 13, but not in IE7/8/9 and Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/kj9p4/114/

Basically, I want to type in a textbox and scroll to an item in the list, which has the value that I just keyed in. This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="t" id="t" />
</br>    
<select size="3"> 
       <option value="1">value 1</option> 
       <option value="2">value 2</option> 
       <option value="3">value 3</option> 
       <option value="4">value 4</option> 
       <option value="5">value 5</option> 
       <option value="6">value 6</option>
       <option value="7">value 7</option> 
       <option value="8">value 8</option> 
       <option value="9">value 9</option> 
       <option value="10">value 10</option>            
 <select>
```

and this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#t").keyup(function () {
        scrollToElement();                
    });
});


function scrollToElement(){
    var $s = $('select');
    var v = $("#t").val();

    var ele = $s.find('[value="'+v+'"]');
    var optionTop = $s.find('[value="'+ v +'"]').offset().top;       
    var selectTop = $s.offset().top;    
    $s.scrollTop($s.scrollTop() + (optionTop - selectTop));
}
```

​
Is there anyone who experience the same ? Why jQuery do not work for  in Chrome and IE ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240385/getting-the-height-of-an-option-element-with-javascript/4240492#4240492. Basically there is not really an offset for an option element.

Answer (score 0):

"Basically, I want to type in a textbox and scroll to an item in the list, which has the value that I just keyed in" The code below will fulfil your need

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#t").keyup(function () {
        scrollToElement();                
    });
});


function scrollToElement(){ 
    var s = $('select');
    var t =$('#t').val();
    var option = t - 1;
   s.find('option:eq('+option+')').attr('selected','selected');
}
```

Comment: If it's merely scrolling, this may fit a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/kj9p4/117/.