# How to scroll current dropdown list position up or down by a specified number of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, html-select

Given a dropdown list with many items:

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
    ...
    <option value="100">Item #100</option>
</select>
```

I'm wondering how to write a jQuery function to scroll up/down by a specified number of items.

**Note: There are similar SO questions for scrolling to a specified element but how would I know which element this is? All that should be passed in the function interface is the number of elements to scroll up or down *from the current scroll position*...**

Comment: Steve can you give an example?

Comment: @Zword Something like: `function scrollByItems(selectId, numberOfItems, isUp) { ... }`?

Comment: I believe, you cannot control the `scrollTop` of the list that drops down from a `<select>` or is it a `multiple` `<select>`

Comment: @techfoobar Have seen [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) but couldn't see how to get it to work as it relates to number of pixels rather than items

Comment: See comment added to the bottom of the q about possible duplicates - neither seem to answer this exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be fairly easy if it were possible to find out the height of each `<option>` in the `<select>`. However, it seems this isn't trivial (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240385/getting-the-height-of-an-option-element-with-javascript#4240492)). Best I could come up with is the following:

```
function scrollUp($select, numOptions) {
    // Assuming default of 8 visible options in select without a 'size' attribute
    var selectSize = $select.attr('size') || 8;
    // Option height calculated below - may not be completely accurate?
    var approxOptionHeight = Math.floor($select.height() / selectSize);
    var newScrollTop = $select.scrollTop() - (numOptions * approxOptionHeight);
    if (newScrollTop < 0) {
        newScrollTop = 0;
    }
    $select.scrollTop(newScrollTop);
}
```